# Rounding a number in Python but keeping ending zeros

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I've been working on a script that takes data from an Excel spreadsheet, rounds the numbers, and removes the decimal point, for example, 2606.89579999999 becomes 26069. However, I need the number to round to two decimal places even if there would be a trailing zero, so 2606.89579999999 should become 260690.

I currently have it so `i` takes the data from the cell in Excel, and rounds it to two decimal places (`i = round(i, 2)`) which gives me the single decimal point in the above example.

I've tried figuring out how to get this to work with `Decimal`, but I can't seem to get it working.

All other numbers that get rounded, if the rounded value doesn't end in '0', work fine with `round(i, 2)`, but if the numbers just so happen to end in *.x0, that 0 gets dropped off and messes with the data.

Comment: I think I've just figured it out - using `i = ('%.2f' %i)` seems to work. I'm going to test it with other numbers to verify that it works

Comment: 2606.89579999999 should become 260690 or 2606.90?

Comment: @SethKoberg I updated my answer with decimal example if you somehow missed that (edited post alot to be more clear and precise)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add zeros to a float after the decimal point in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619096/add-zeros-to-a-float-after-the-decimal-point-in-python)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As you are talking about trailing zeros, this is a question about representation as string,
you can use

```
>>> "%.2f" % round(2606.89579999999, 2)
'2606.90'
```

Or use modern style with `format` function:

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(round(2606.89579999999, 2))
'2606.90'
```

and remove point with `replace` or `translate` (`_` refers to result of previous command in python console):

```
>>> _.translate(None, '.')
'260690'
```

Note that rounding is not needed here, as `.2f` format applyies the same rounding:

```
>>> "%.2f" % 2606.89579999999
'2606.90'
```

But as you mentioned excel, you probably would opt to roll your own rounding function, or use [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), as `float.round` can lead to strange results due to float representation:

```
>>> round(2.675, 2)
2.67
>>> round(2606.89579999999, 2)
2606.89
```

With decimal use [quantize](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> x = Decimal('2606.8950000000001')
# Decimal('2606.8950000000001')
>>> '{}'.format(x.quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN))
'2606.90'
```

That, for your original task, becomes:

```
>>> x = Decimal('2606.8950000000001')
>>> int((x*100).quantize(1, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN))
260690
```

And the reason of strange rounding comes to the front with `Decimal`:

```
>>> x = Decimal(2606.8950000000001)
# Decimal('2606.89499999999998181010596454143524169921875') # internal float repr
```

Comment: No need for the `round` call: the `.2f` will already do the rounding for you.

Comment: `%.2f` already does the rounding for you, so you can also use: `"%.2f" % (2606.89579999999)` or `format(2606.89579999999, '.2f')`

Comment: @MarkDickinson was not sure that it rounds exactly the same way, which in fact it does

Comment: @alko: Mostly it does. :-)  There are some oddities in Python 2.6 and earlier, though.  But if you stick to Python 3 or Python 2.7 you're safe.

Comment: @MarkDickinson i just checked with 2.7 and 3.3 cP and PyPy, and forgot 2.6 :)

Comment: py3.7.12 `round(2606.89579999999, 2)==2606.9`

Answer (score 26):

As of Python 3.6, you can also use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) to inline format the number. In this case, the desired format is floating point with 2 decimal places so you would use `.2f` as the format specifier:

```py
x = 2606.89579999999
x = round(x, 2)      # not strictly necessary as format will round for you
print(f'{x:.2f}')
```

Output:

```
2606.90
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(2606.89579999999).replace('.', '')
'260690'
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to dynamically change the number of decimal places, you can use the modification below:

```
def formatNumber(n, digits):
    formatter = '{:.' + '{}'.format(digits) + 'f}'
    x = round(n, digits)
    return formatter.format(x)

x = 2606.89579999999
digits = 2

formatted_number = formatNumber(x, digits)
```

That way, all you have to do, it to change the `digits` variable. This will return:

```
2606.90
```

Comment: replace `n` by `x`, right?

Comment: @j35t3r you are absolutely right. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I the answers that I saw here did not satisfy me.
So here my solution:

```
def round_with_padding(value, round_digits):
    return format(round(value,round_digits), "."+str(round_digits)+"f")
```

Hope you like it

Answer (score -8):

```
>>> int (round (2606.89579999999,2)*100)
260690
```

Comment: Bad idea.  `>>> int(round(0.29, 2) * 100)` -> `28`.