# Python: How to round the float value to 1.20 instead of 1.2

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I found that if I use round function to some float values, it is OK to round to two decimals, but sometimes, for example, `round(myvalu, 2)`  it will return `1.2` instead of `1.20`, but actually I want every returned value is rounded to two decimals, i.e. `1.20` instead of `1.2`. What should I do?

Comment: Look at this post how to format floats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a number in python but keeping ending zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros)

Answer (score 1):

That's something you'd do when displaying the number.

Try

```
'%.2f' % num
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am wondering whether there is a function that replaces the function round to get what I mentioned in the question?

Comment: In terms of the actual number (the bits) 1.2 == 1.20... the only difference is the visual representation.

Comment: Also, look at round() ... 2nd are is # of decimal places. But you'll still need to format to get desired string representation.