# Comma as decimal point in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. 
In python, I wish to convert float variables to string variable with 2 decimal places and decimal comma.

For example, 3.1415 --> 3,14

it works fine. But when I convert 1.20, it gives 1,2 instead of 1,20. 
I want the latter one
Is there an easy way to achieve that? Thank You Guys

My code is in the following:

```
s=float(input())
a=round(s,2)
x=str(a)
y=x.replace('.',','))
print(y)
```

Comment: Hi, could you post the code you are currently using for the conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a number in Python but keeping ending zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros)

Comment: are you expecting to round the decimal or just strip the remaining decimals ?

Comment: round to 2decimals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
>>> num = 1.201020
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(num).replace('.', ',')
'1,20'
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works?  is {:#.2f} treating the variable as float or string? Thank you

Comment: It is string formatting. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get thousand an decimal separators using the format() function with the "f" format type.

```
var_float = 1234.5
str_float = "{:,.2f}".format(var_float)
print(str_float)
>> 1,234.50
```

However, format() doesn't allow to configure the characters used as decimal and thousand separators. According to the [docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0378/#main-proposal-from-nick-coghlan-originally-called-proposal-i):

> This technique is completely general but it is awkward in the one case where the commas and periods need to be swapped:
>
> ```
> format(n, "6,f").replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")
> ```

So in order to get your expected output you need to add replacements like these:

```
var_float = 1234.5
str_float = "{:,.2f}".format(var_float).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")
print(str_float)
>> 1.234,50
```

Other option is to set the appropriate locale so format() knows what characters to use. This requires the usage of the "n" format type, but you lose control over the number of decimal digits.

Example for the Spanish locale:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_es')
var_float = 1234.5
print('{:n}'.format(var_float))
>> 1.234,5
```

Note that changing the locale will affect any future formatting.

More information on formatting in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)