# Python: Float to string with variable number of positions after the decimal point

Tags: python

I need to represent float values as strings with different number of positions after the decimal point, which should be set by **variable**, not hardcoded like `"%.2f"`.

Now I'm using `round` approach:

```
def float_to_str(value, digits):
    return str(round(value, digits))
```

This function cuts extra digits, so the result has **no more** that specified number of digits. But it doesn't add trailing zeros.

```
float_to_str(1.3573, 2)   =>  "1.35"  - OK 
float_to_str(1.3573, 3)   =>  "1.357" - OK 
float_to_str(1.3000, 2)   =>  "1.3"   - NOT OK (needed "1.30")
```

Is there a nicer way to implement this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `format` function, which can use syntax similar to `"%.2f"`, and format that as well:

```
def float_to_str(value, digits):
    return "{value:.{digits}f}".format(value=value, digits=digits)
```

Answer (score 3):

The formatting mini language also allows for nested replacement:

```py
def float_to_str(value, digits):
    return f"{value:.{digits}f}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` to denote a variable width in your format string:

```
def float_to_str(value, digits):
    return "%.*f" % (digits, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
def float_to_str(value, digits):
    formatting = '{:.' + str(digits) + 'f}'
    return formatting.format(round(value, digits))
```

For more information about rounding a number but keeping ending zeros in python, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

Using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is a possible way to go:

```py
def float_to_str(x, n):
    return f"{x:.{n}f}"
```