# Python : Round float number keeping 0

Tags: python, rounding

I need to round only the last 2 positives of a float number in Python

EX:

- 0.000000302329303 -> 0.00000031
- 0.09838 -> 0.10
- 0.0003299 -> 0.00033

Is this possible in a simple way like round?

Comment: Why does `0.09838` not result in `0.098`?

Comment: I was wrong in the condition, 0.09838, It should be 0.099

Comment: Are you sure it should not be `0.098`? The next digit is `3`.

Comment: Always with the 2 last positive digits to up.

Comment: Yeah, i need every two digits after 0 rounded to up. In any case that happens

Comment: check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it this way

```
from math import ceil, floor

def float_round(num, direction = floor):
    zeros = 0
    number = num
    while number < 0.1:
        number *= 10
        zeros += 1
    places = zeros + 2
    return direction(num * (10**places)) / float(10**places)

a = 43.0093
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 43.01
a = 0.018552876
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 0.019
a = 0.03352
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 0.034
a = 0.0998844
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 0.1
a = 0.1093
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 0.11
a = 33.0093
print(float_round(a, ceil)) ## 33.01
```

Thanks to everyone, the answer was essential for me to be able to think of something.

Answer (score 2):

I think your examples are wrong, but just adjust the code as you need:

```
# this code doesn't work if some are defined as 0.123 and others as .123
a = 0.000000302329303
nb_characters = len(str(a))
rounding_expr = "%%.%sf" % (nb_characters - 4)
rounded_a = float(rounding_expr % a)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to calculate the exponent with log in base 10, and take its negative value:

```
import math

z = 1
x = 0.09838
rounded_x = round(x, math.ceil(-math.log10(x)) + z)
```

Now you can change z to set the number of digits

Notice that in general using round might convert the float into scientific representation (mantissa and exponent), so in very small numbers it might be less accurate.