# Why is my answer not rounding to two decimal points using the Round function in python?

Tags: python, rounding

#Below is my code. What is wrong with the code where it wont pick up the round? I searched stack overflow and it seems right based off search results, but something is off. I got the correct answer, but my answer is displayed incorrectly, should be 33.60 assuming the bill is 150, tip would be 12, and 5 people split the bill.

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
Bill_A = float(input("What was the total bill?"))
Tip_A = float(input("How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15?"))
Bill_Split = float(input("How many people to split the bill?"))
 
#Convert Tip to decimal for calculation.
Tip_B = (Tip_A / 100) + 1.00
 
Total_Bill = ((Bill_A / Bill_Split) * Tip_B)
 
Total_Bill2 = round(Total_Bill, 2)
 
print(f"Each person should pay: ${Total_Bill2}" )
```

Comment: What's the answer displaying?

Comment: It is showing 33.6 probably the answer is 33.60 and the zero gets removed

Comment: I ran your script and got 33.6. What's wrong?

Comment: If you're asking how to keep the trailing zeroes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros/19986686#19986686

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding a number in Python but keeping ending zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986662/rounding-a-number-in-python-but-keeping-ending-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to show 33.60. If so, use this code. I have used %.2f to set two decimal places

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
Bill_A = float(input("What was the total bill?"))
Tip_A = float(input("How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15?"))
Bill_Split = float(input("How many people to split the bill?"))
 
#Convert Tip to decimal for calculation.
Tip_B = (Tip_A / 100) + 1.00
 
Total_Bill = ((Bill_A / Bill_Split) * Tip_B)
 
print(f"Each person should pay: %.2f" % Total_Bill )
```

Comment: Thank you! I am struggling to understand how the %.2f works and the % before total_bill. I guess with practice it will come, but is there an easy explanation to explain that? And why didn't the round function work?

Comment: Yeah, they are very handy, make sure you learn them!