# Round Float Values not keeping rounding decimal points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, rounding

[image: Image Output]

I'm trying to round float series pulled from yfinance to two decimal places. Despite using `round(2)` and `astype('float32')`, the dataframe refuses to keep the round and shows multiple decimal places for each series. What am I doing wrong?

```
def clean_df(df):
    return (df
    .stack(level=0)
    .swaplevel(0,1,axis=0)
    .sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True)
    .reset_index(level=[0,1])
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "Symbol"})
    .round({'Open': 2, 'High': 2,'Low': 2,'Close': 2,'Volume': 0})
    .astype({'Symbol':'string','Close':'float32','Open':'float32','High':'float32','Low':'float32','Volume':'int32'})
    )
```

Comment: The only way to guarantee display with a certain number of decimal places is to convert to a string, using e.g. one of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19986662/9473764)

Comment: @Nick that's not the only way. You can use the Decimal module to handle decimal values https://beepscore.com/website/2018/10/12/using-pandas-with-python-decimal.html

Comment: Float32 is the wrong type to use, it can only hold about 5 digits before inaccuracy sets in.

Comment: I'm using float32 to preserve memory. Stock prices should only have 2 decimal places so I'm fine with the inaccuracy on that front.

Comment: @greenguy, rather than count money to the dollar, count to the 0.01, then all values are whole numbers.  With intermediate calculations that might incur a small +/- fraction, round to the near whole number.   _Display_ values with `x/100` to 2 places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the float format display/[*option*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) :

```
pd.set_option("display.float_format", lambda x: "%.2f" % x)

def clean_df(df):
    return (df
    .stack(level=1)
    .swaplevel(0,1,axis=0)
    .sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True)
    .reset_index(level=[0,1])
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "Symbol"})
    )

df = yf.download("AAPL XOM", start="1980-12-12", end="2023-05-27")
```

Output :

```
print(clean_df(df))

      Symbol       Date  Adj Close  Close   High    Low   Open     Volume
0       AAPL 1980-12-12       0.10   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.13  469033600
1       AAPL 1980-12-15       0.09   0.12   0.12   0.12   0.12  175884800
2       AAPL 1980-12-16       0.09   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.11  105728000
3       AAPL 1980-12-17       0.09   0.12   0.12   0.12   0.12   86441600
4       AAPL 1980-12-18       0.09   0.12   0.12   0.12   0.12   73449600
...      ...        ...        ...    ...    ...    ...    ...        ...
21403    XOM 2023-05-22     104.97 104.97 107.04 104.88 105.84   12882000
21404    XOM 2023-05-23     106.40 106.40 108.22 105.75 105.99   14394400
21405    XOM 2023-05-24     107.59 107.59 108.51 106.73 107.38   16340300
21406    XOM 2023-05-25     105.66 105.66 106.43 104.71 105.94   14316500
21407    XOM 2023-05-26     104.97 104.97 106.95 104.83 106.47   12367300

[21408 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: This would just change the display of decimals though right? I want the numbers to be mutated.

Comment: Then, add `.round(2)` as a last chain of the returned *DataFrame* in `clean_df`.

Comment: For whatever reason that doesn't work either. it just doesnt change

Comment: You can't create a float32 number like 106.73 exactly, because this number can't be represented as a float32. The closest is 106.73000335693359375, which is what you see.
This is just how floating point numbers work.

Comment: @greenguy Notice that 105.750000 displays exactly, because 0.75 is ¾ which is an exact power-of-two fraction.  Notice that 106.730003 does not display exactly, because 0.73 is not an exact power-of-two fraction.  See also [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)

Comment: I'm referring to the rounding not working. I only want 2 decimal places in the data.

step 1: convert to float 32 to reduce memory
step 2: round or just remove trailing decimals past 2 to completey remove the extra numbers from my data frame.