# "%11f" notation in Python printing too many digits

Tags: python, string

In Python, I am trying to convert floating point numbers to strings such that the string is exactly 12 characters long: the first character is a space and the remaining characters can be filled with the digits (and decimal point if needs be) of the number to be converted to a string.  Also, the numbers need to be expressed in decimal form (no scientific notation).  I am working inside a fixed format in a particular file; hence the exact parameters stated above.  It can be assumed that all numbers I'm working with are less than 1e12, i.e., that all numbers can be expressed with

I am using

```
s = " %11f" % number
```

Most of the floating point numbers convert to a string fitting my formatting parameters just fine; however, some of the larger numbers don't.  For example,

```
print " %11f" % 325918.166005444
```

gives `325918.166005`.  This takes up 13 characters, not 11.

Why is my code doing this, and how can I fix this?  I'd like to keep as much precision as possible (i.e., simply truncating the fractional portion of the number is not a good enough solution).

If Python version is important, I'm using 2.7.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg, each number will need a different `precision` value, depending on many whole digits there are.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg I assume that's because rounding is required rather than truncating: "simply truncating the fractional portion of the number is not a good enough solution". Unless it's *my* turn to misread.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify a precision, so the default precision for floats, 6, is used. You need both width and precision to get a *precise* (pun not intended) output.

Also note that:

> width is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not
>   specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.

So the precision does more to decide the overall width of the string here.

You could apply *new style formatting* to gain more control with specifying the width and precision:

```
>>> num = 325918.166005444
>>> w = 11
>>> " {:{w}.{p}f}".format(num, w=w, p=len(repr(num))-w-1) # subtract 1 for the dot
' 325918.1660'
```

This, however, assumes that your float is always larger than the *width*, otherwise, you could first pad the float with trailing zeros after the decimal.

Comment: My float is not always larger than the width.  And how could I pad a float with trailing zeroes?  Floats don't store trailing zeroes.

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619096/add-zeros-to-a-float-after-the-decimal-point-in-python

Comment: When I try this solution with `num=1.1`, I get `ValueError: Format specifier missing precision`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Rightly so. Precision in that case is negative/invalid. OP never specified how they wish to handle floats that are shorter than their specified width.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I never specified that the floats were to be longer than their specified width either.  I do want something to handle both cases.

Comment: So how should shorter lengths be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Moses Koledoye's answer, here's what I got to work:

```
num = 325918.166005444
w = 11
p = w-len(str(int(num)))-1
if p <=0: # If it's short enough
   print " %11f" % num
else: # If it's too long
   print " {:{w}.{p}f}".format(num, w=w, p=p)
```