# How do I either remove index of the data frame or replace it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This is my current dataframe.

```
 df =pd.DataFrame({'Observation':index,'x':x,'y':y,'dx':np.round(dx, decimals 
 =2),'vx':np.round(vx, decimals=2),'dy':np.round(dy, 
 decimals=2),'vy':np.round(vy, decimals=2), 'pxy':np.round(pxy, decimals=2)})
 df = df.reindex_axis(['Observation','x','y','dx','vx','dy','vy', 'pxy'], 
 axis=1)
 df.loc['SUM']=df.
 df
```

I would like the my Observation Column to the index of the dataframe. How can I do it? Also, is it possible for the values in columns `dx`,`dy`,`vx`,`vy` and `pxy` to be shown in 2 decimal place?

[image]

Comment: please dont use images..

Comment: @Merlin Then how is he supposed to post the table ?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle copy and paste table as txt. This SO folks can copy the table txt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pandas `set_index()` method to change the index of the data frame to your column values.

```
df.set_index('Observation')
```

[API Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

The API `numpy.round()` is used for rounding a float value and does not append 0 after the decimal point. To achieve this, you need to use python inbuilt function, `format()`. So your code should be :

```
format(x, '.2f')
```

Follow this stack overflow thread for more info: [Add zeros to a float after the decimal point in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619096/add-zeros-to-a-float-after-the-decimal-point-in-python)

Comment: What about the 2 decimal places for the values in specific columns? I tried np.round(), but it didnt work.

Comment: Use the function `format(x,'%.2f')` to achieve this... @user234568

Comment: for rounding you can use the df.round() function too: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly

this will clear the previous index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

this will set the index:

```
df.set_index('Observation', inplace=True)
```

this will show 2 decimal places:

```
df.round(2)
```

Comment: i think reset_index would give you another column called 'index' which you should drop in such cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

This removes the column names:

`df.columns = ['' for index in range(len(df.columns))]`

This removes the [0, 1, 2...] default index:

`df.index = ('' for index in range(len(df.index)))`