# In Python: How can I write floating point numbers in a file using a specified number of figures?

Tags: python, printing, precision

I am trying to write in a file floating point values but I want always to have the numbers represented with 4 figures/numbers.

I already did this for **integers** using the command:

```
f.write("%04d " % my_int_value)
```

In that case if *my_int_value* is **25** it will print in the file:

```
0025
```

if *my_int_value* = **2** it will print in the file:

```
0002
```

*which is exactly what I am looking for!*

**Then**, I tried to do the same for floating point numbers using the command:

```
f.write("%04f " % my_float_value)
```

but now it does not work.

For example if *my_float_value* = **0.03** I would like to print in the file **0.030**

Is this possible? 
and if it is how could someone do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add zeros to a float after the decimal point in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619096/add-zeros-to-a-float-after-the-decimal-point-in-python)

Comment: Indeed the question is answered in the link above, however I could not find it because of the way the question is formulated. Also, the the question is about writing in files (it is slightly different)

Comment: Aren't you also writing in files?

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou A `str` is a `str` it will all act the same whether printed or written.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Yes indeed, you are right. At least, I think is easier now to detect the question for that type of problem, as I when I searched for my problem I could not find the older one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways:

```
print("%.3f " % my_float_value) # Using formatting for Python2.7
```

or

```
print("{0:.3f} ".format(my_float_value)) # Using modern string formatting
```

or

```
print(f"{my_float_value:.3f}") # A newer form of string formatting
```